# Stock dividend payments; how is payment made?

Tags: stocks, dividends

Dividend payments; where do they get paid into?

Comment: do you own shares of a company or do you own shares in a mutual fund/ETF?

Answer (score 2):

If you own the shares directly, they're paid into your brokerage account where you hold the shares. If you own an ETF or mutual fund that owns dividend-paying shares, the fund is paid. See your fund's prospectus to determine whether the dividends are paid out to investors (which will show up in your brokerage account) or if they are re-invested into the fund.

Answer (score 1):

They either get paid directly into your bank account if you have one linked with the share registry, or you get sent a cheque.